# Umbraco 5 with MVC4 and Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to install umbraco 5 with MVC4 (beta)? I was also wondering whether it's possible to use Table Storage with umbraco 5 instead of SQL. Please give samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this is possible, although you might want to reconsider in light of the [announcement](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx/), if that doesn't deter you - check this [sample](http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/11/25/a-blob-storage-hive-provider-for-umbraco-5-beta/) of a hive provider w/- cloud storage

Comment: Ah alright the announcement comes as a surprise to me. Your sample looks good, though.